# Using second order perturbation to calculate electron self-energy caused by electron-phonon interaction

Tags: condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, self-energy

Assume the electron-phonon interaction is given by
$$
H_{ep} = \sum_{k q} D(q) c_{k+q}^\dagger c_k (a_q + a_{-q}^\dagger).
$$
In the theory of superconductivity, the electron-electron effective Hamiltonian caused by the above electron-phonon interaction is calculated by a canonical transformation ([Schrieffer–Wolff transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrieffer%E2%80%93Wolff_transformation)) $H_s = e^s H e^{-s}$. Apply this method we will obtain
$$
H_s = \sum_{k q} |D(q)|^2 \frac{\omega_q}{(\epsilon_{k+q} - \epsilon_k)^2 - \omega_q^2} c_{k+q}^\dagger c_k c_{k'-q}^\dagger c_{k'} .
$$
Now exchange the $c_k$ and $c_{k'-q}^\dagger$ in the above expression, we get the electron-electron interaction
$$
\sum_{k q} |D(q)|^2 \frac{\omega_q}{(\epsilon_{k+q} - \epsilon_k)^2 - \omega_q^2} c_{k+q}^\dagger c_{k'-q}^\dagger c_{k'} c_k,
$$
and the commutator gives us a self-energy term as well
$$
\sum_{k q} |D(q)|^2 \frac{\omega_q}{(\epsilon_{k+q} - \epsilon_k)^2 - \omega_q^2} c_{k}^\dagger c_k.
$$
Here is my question, how to use the second order perturbation method instead to calculate this self-energy term? What kinds of Feynman diagram are involved? I tried some diagrams, but I can not obtain the same answer.